# JanusGraph Hbase repeatedly calls HBaseKeyColumnValueStore.getFilters()

Tags: java, hbase, cloudera, janusgraph

We are running a Java application, which uses a JanusGraph backed by a Hbase table on a Cloudera cluster.

We use the janusgraph-hbase dependency, v0.2.

When running our app, we see these lines appear in the logs:

```
20180330 15:00:27;DEBUG;HBaseKeyColumnValueStore:145;Generated HBase Filter FilterList AND (2/2): [ColumnRangeFilter [\x00\x05h\xA0\xD2\xA3m\x18, \x00\x05h\xA0\xD2\xEF\xC4\x10), ColumnPaginationFilter (1024, 0)]
20180330 15:00:32;DEBUG;HBaseKeyColumnValueStore:145;Generated HBase Filter FilterList AND (2/2): [ColumnRangeFilter [\x00\x05h\xA0\xD2\xEF\xC4\x10, \x00\x05h\xA0\xD3<\x17 ), ColumnPaginationFilter (1024, 0)]
20180330 15:00:37;DEBUG;HBaseKeyColumnValueStore:145;Generated HBase Filter FilterList AND (2/2): [ColumnRangeFilter [\x00\x05h\xA0\xD3<\x17 , \x00\x05h\xA0\xD3\x88n\x18), ColumnPaginationFilter (1024, 0)]
20180330 15:00:42;DEBUG;HBaseKeyColumnValueStore:145;Generated HBase Filter FilterList AND (2/2): [ColumnRangeFilter [\x00\x05h\xA0\xD3\x88n\x18, \x00\x05h\xA0\xD3\xD4\xC1(), ColumnPaginationFilter (1024, 0)]
20180330 15:00:47;DEBUG;HBaseKeyColumnValueStore:145;Generated HBase Filter FilterList AND (2/2): [ColumnRangeFilter [\x00\x05h\xA0\xD3\xD4\xC1(, \x00\x05h\xA0\xD4!\x18 ), ColumnPaginationFilter (1024, 0)]
20180330 15:00:52;DEBUG;HBaseKeyColumnValueStore:145;Generated HBase Filter FilterList AND (2/2): [ColumnRangeFilter [\x00\x05h\xA0\xD4!\x18 , \x00\x05h\xA0\xD4mk0), ColumnPaginationFilter (1024, 0)]
20180330 15:00:57;DEBUG;HBaseKeyColumnValueStore:145;Generated HBase Filter FilterList AND (2/2): [ColumnRangeFilter [\x00\x05h\xA0\xD4mk0, \x00\x05h\xA0\xD4\xB9\xC2(), ColumnPaginationFilter (1024, 0)]
20180330 15:01:02;DEBUG;HBaseKeyColumnValueStore:145;Generated HBase Filter FilterList AND (2/2): [ColumnRangeFilter [\x00\x05h\xA0\xD4\xB9\xC2(, \x00\x05h\xA0\xD5\x06\x158), ColumnPaginationFilter (1024, 0)]
20180330 15:01:07;DEBUG;HBaseKeyColumnValueStore:145;Generated HBase Filter FilterList AND (2/2): [ColumnRangeFilter [\x00\x05h\xA0\xD5\x06\x158, \x00\x05h\xA0\xD5Rl0), ColumnPaginationFilter (1024, 0)]
```

And so on.

- If these logs are expected, what are they about and is it safe to filter them out of our logs?
- If they are not, would closing the JanusGraph and reopening it only when
  needed solve this?

Thank you in advance.